# Can I instantiate an object inside the class that it was passed into (as a parameter)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Dashboard component, inside which I want to display multiple Charts (these charts can be line charts, bubble charts, you name it). For this example, I want to display a LineChart. You can see LineChart being passed in as the chartType value.

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from './Chart';
import LineChart from '../LineChart';

const Dashboard = function () {

  return (
    <div>
      <Chart chartType={LineChart} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Chart acts like a generic wrapper, all it does is handle rendering, it shouldn't matter what chartType it is given as a parameter. If a LineChart obj is passed into it, it should render the LineChart component, if a ScatterChart obj then the ScatterChart component.

```
class Chart extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
    this.ref = React.createRef();
    
    this.myChartObj = new LineChart(props); // I DONT WANT THIS AS IT IS HARDCODING THE LINE CHART TYPE
    // this.myChartObj = new props.chartType(props); // DOESNT WORK
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myChartObj.create(this.ref.current);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.myChartObj.update(this.ref.current);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.ref} role="graphics-datachart" />
    );
  }
}
```

So **I'm wondering how to instantiate a new LineChart object inside Chart's constructor** by using the ChartType param. As you can see in the code, it's currently hardcoded with `this.chartObj = new LineChart(props);` Ideally, the solution would be something like this: `this.chartObj = new props.chartType(props);` because there's no hardcoding but it doesn't work and throws *A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter* error.

Could anyone assist? Surely it should be OK to pass a class as a parameter and later use that parameter value to instantiate a new object of that class..? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit: I'm aware that the error is being generated by my linter, but the question still stands as to how I instantiate an obj from a parameter. I'm getting a similar error in unit testing, which means that simply silencing my linter won't fit anything: `TypeError: props.chartType is not a constructor`

[Unit test results*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AIvG.png)

note: I'm using "chartType" in the stack question but its equivalent to d3Chart in screenshot

Comment: The error you're getting is from something like your IDE or a "linter"; it is not actually a JavaScript error.

Comment: The first thing I'm thinking is a switch case on `props.chartType`. Is not elegant I know but would work.